# How can I limit a Jenkins build step to ONLY given changeset?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, changeset

I'm using Jenkins declarative pipeline and I'm trying to execute a specific build stage only if changes were made ONLY in a specified directory.

So my directory hierarchy looks something like this:

```
root
 ├─ some-directory
 |   ├─ sub-directory
 |   |   └─ file-1
 |   ├─ file-1
 |   └─ file-2
 ├─ another-directory
 |   ├─ file-1
 |   └─ file-2
 ├─ file-x
 └─ file-y
```

This is the current code:

```groovy
stage ("Deploy branches") {
    agent any

    when { 
        allOf {
            not { branch 'master' }
            changeset "some-directory/**"
        }
    }

    steps {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This deploys whenever something was changed in "some-directory" but also when something outside of "some-directory" was changed. I would like this step to run if nothing else but the contents of "some-directory" were changed.

This is what [the Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) say about the "changeset" directive:

> changeset
>
> Execute the stage if the build’s SCM changeset contains one or more files matching the given string or glob. Example: when { changeset "**/*.js" }
>
> By default the path matching will be case insensitive, this can be turned off with the caseSensitive parameter, for example: when { changeset glob: "ReadMe.*", caseSensitive: true }

"If the changeset *contains* one or more files matching the given string or glob." means the pipelines works as designed, but what I nwould eed is

"If the files in the changeset match *only* the given string or glob."

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about that in the docs or somewhere else on the internet.

Do you have any suggestions how I could make this possible?

Comment: Try `changeset "some-directory/**/*"`

Comment: But this won't fix the problem, that the pipeline will react on changes _outside_ of "some-directory". I'm gonna make my question more precise on this point.

Comment: I believe this means, that the pipeline will react once it finds this location within your changeset. Since this folder is always present and its a match, it reacts - even though the change is not in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that `changeset` cannot do what you are trying to achieve ; but it can be replaced with an `expression` shelling out to compute the Git diff and do the relevant filtering. I had a similar issue and it worked fine for me.

The following should work for your use-case:

```groovy
stage ("Deploy branches") {
    agent any

    when { 
        allOf {
            not { branch 'master' }
            changeset "some-directory/**"
            expression {  // there are changes in some-directory/...
                sh(returnStatus: true, script: 'git diff  origin/master --name-only | grep --quiet "^some-directory/.*"') == 0
            }
            expression {   // ...and nowhere else.
                sh(returnStatus: true, script: 'git diff origin/master --name-only | grep --quiet --invert-match "^some-directory/.*"') == 1
            }
        }
    }

    steps {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(this hardcodes the comparison with `origin/master`, which was my use-case ; if that’s not sophisticated enough it might be possible to use some Jenkins variable containing the target branch of the pull-request.)

Comment: It looks like `== 0` and `== 1` are checking the exit status code, correct? I wasn't able to reproduce a `1` exit code for a `--quiet --invert-match` grep. Is there a way to force `git` to produce the exit code? Alternatively, could the `-c` flag be used to count matches?

Answer (score 0):

Some old jenkins pipeline versions doesn't support ***when*** statement.

You can check for changes like this too:

```
def rc = sh(
  script: "git status -s ${dir} | grep -q ${dir}",
  returnStatus: true
)
if(!rc) {
  doSomething(dir)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We were not able to use `when { changeset "**/*.js" }`, because the pipline was generated dynamically and it is not possible to use `when {}` inside of a `script {}`. You will get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'when' found among steps

We created a wrapper function to check for changes by using the same implementation as the `changeset` declaration does.

```groovy
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.when.impl.ChangeSetConditional

def caseSensitive = false

def hasChanges(String pattern) {
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    def conditional = new ChangeSetConditional(pattern)

    for (set in changeLogSets) {
        def entries = set.items
        for (entry in entries) {
            if (conditional.changeSetMatches(entry, pattern, caseSensitive)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```groovy
script {
  for (library in libraries) {
    def changesFound = hasChanges("${library.path}/**");
  
    if (changesFound) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```